# Methods to Hide/Encrypt Data

Tags: security, encryption

What are the alternatives to Hide/Encrypt Data on disk. Like:

1. Encrypt using normal encryption alogrighm.
2. Remove first 16 (or so) bytes from file and store it somewhere else. This will propably make it unreadable.
3. Shuffle bytes of file with tracking.

etc. What are other alternatives?

I need to encrypt data in 3 to 4 ways/level so that, **recovery tools cannot recover** it.

Note: All methods should be able to get back the original data.

Comment: Please specify your goal. The method of security protection (encryption, obfuscation etc) depends on what attacks you want to counteract.

Comment: I need to encrypt data in 3 to 4 ways/level so that, recovery tools cannot recover it.

Comment: That's not a goal, that is one of possible ways. The goal is to secure yourself from (what?)

Comment: Also you need to update your question rather than answer in comments, as other people might want to understand your question as well.

Comment: Isn't "recovery tools cannot recover it" a goal? For me, it is.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to encrypt using existing tools such as Truecrypt, PGP etc., such that a forensic tool  will not retrieve the datunless they have your passphrase. This is standard. What do you need to do that requires more?

If, however, you are storing something very sensitive, there is no way to prevent against the [Rubber Hose](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/10/rubber_hose_cry.html) attack, so perhaps multiple layers of encryption could provide you with a level of deniability. There used to be a tool called, I think, RubberHose which encrypted volumes in such a way it was impossible to prove whether there was any further level of encryption used.

Answer (score 0):

Just use some kind of standard encryption algorithm.  These are tried and tested - anything you try to do yourself is open to you leaving some kind of security hole.

Answer (score 0):

[**stego**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography#Digital_steganography)

"Steghide is a steganography program that is able to hide data in various kinds of image- and audio-files. The color- respectivly sample-frequencies are not changed thus making the embedding resistant against first-order statistical tests. "

http://steghide.sourceforge.net/

"Magikfs is a highly secure steganographic filesystem"

http://magikfs.sourceforge.net/

- *The most secure system any one person can imagine is likely not
  secure.*